# how to use count with join

Tags: sql, mysql, count

I am looking a way to present all the data in table T1 with a count on the number of form_id from T2 in the intended outcome. The common column between the two tables is the organization id. The outcome should also include those have zero count of the form_id. How can I write this query? Much thanks!

I could only manage the count but can't seem to join the table with T1, it only shows two columns of the organization id and the number of forms.

select

```
T1.organization_id, count(T2.form_id) as NumberofForms from T2
left join 
T1 on T1.organization_id=T2.organization_id
group by 
T1.organization_id
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to put your query as written above into a subquery, and then join this result back to your original table.

```
select T1.*, X.NumberofForms
from
    T1 inner join 
    (
        select T1.organization_id, count(T2.form_id) as NumberofForms
        from T2
        left join T1 on T1.organization_id = T2.organization_id
        group by T1.organization_id
    ) X
    on T1.organization_id = X.organization_id
```

Per your question in comments, you can repeat this approach to include a count for another table (but this is only by way of example as I don't know the column names from your third table):

```
select T1.*, X.NumberofForms, Y.NumberofResponses
from
    T1 inner join 
    (
        select T1.organization_id, count(T2.form_id) as NumberofForms
        from T2
        left join T1 on T1.organization_id = T2.organization_id
        group by T1.organization_id
    ) X
    on T1.organization_id = X.organization_id
    inner join 
    (
        select T1.organization_id, count(T3.response_id) as NumberofResponses
        from T3
        left join T1 on T1.organization_id = T3.organization_id
        group by T1.organization_id
    ) Y 
    on T1.organization_id = Y.organization_id
```

Comment: Can I ask how can I edit the query if I want to count from another table e.g. T3? That means my outcome will show all the data from T1 with number of forms from T2 and number of responses from T3?

Comment: That is perfect thank you so much! It worked so well :)